# mysqli - How to return false on 0 affected rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The `deleteItem` method returns `true` even if the item isn't deleted. How can `$mysqli->affected_rows` be used in this particular case to check and return false if there are no changes to the database?

```
public function deleteItem($item_id)
{
    $userItemIDS = array();

    $userItemIDS = $this->helperClass->userItemIDS();

    $q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("DELETE i, s FROM items i
    LEFT JOIN save_list s
        ON i.id = s.item_id
        WHERE i.id = ? AND s.item_id = ?
    AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM pending_wins WHERE item_id = ?)
    AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM bids WHERE item_id = ?)");

    if( $q != false && in_array($item_id, $userItemIDS) )
    {
        $q->bind_param("iiii", $item_id, $item_id, $item_id, $item_id);
        $q->execute();
        $q->close();
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: because you didn't actually check affected rows? you'd need `return ($q->affected_row() != 0)` or whatever...

Comment: I know that. I just want to know how the method should be structured. Should I add another if after `if( $q != false && in_a`...? Just curious on how others handle this.

Comment: I wouldn't return false at all. the calling code would have no way of knowing if you hit 0 rows because nothing matched, or you hit 0 rows because the query blew up. return false on failure, and then return num_rows on "success" and the calling code can decide what to do.

Comment: That makes sense. So just for reference, how would you write the code from my question. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment request, pseudo-ish code:

```
if (ok to run query) {
   $q = "...build/prepare/bind query...";
   if ($q->execute() === false) {
       return false; // query failed
   } else {
       return $q->rowCount(); // return number of rows affected
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What about the `$q->close();`? It doesn't get used?

Comment: no need. php (eventually) cleans up when varaibles go out-of-scope. you can explicitly close() if you want to, but it's not necessary in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

this is how it have to be.

```
public function deleteItem($item_id)
{
    $userItemIDS = $this->helperClass->userItemIDS();
    if( !in_array($item_id, $userItemIDS) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $sql = "...";
    $q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $q->bind_param("iiii", $item_id, $item_id, $item_id, $item_id);
    $q->execute();
    return (bool)$this->db->mysqli->affected_rows;
}
```